# Не работают кнопки SceneBuilder в JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, scene-builder

Кнопки нажимаются, но ничего не происходит. И так только в этом окне.

```
package com.example.myapp;   

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;
//                                                  Авторизация
public class app6Controller {

    @FXML
    private ResourceBundle resources;

    @FXML
    private URL location;

    @FXML
    private Button exitButton;

    @FXML
    private TextField loginField;

    @FXML
    private PasswordField passwordField;

    @FXML
    private Button regButton;

    @FXML
    private Button signButton;

    @FXML
    void initialize() {
        signButton.setOnAction(event -> {
            String login = loginField.getText().trim();
            String password = passwordField.getText().trim();

            if(!login.equals("") && !password.equals("")){
                loginUser(login, password);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Error");
            }
        });
        exitButton.setOnAction(event -> {
            System.out.println("Всё работает");
        });
        regButton.setOnAction(event -> {
            regButton.getScene().getWindow().hide();
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("hello-view2.fxml"));
            try {
                loader.load();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Parent root = loader.getRoot();
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 699, 500));
            stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
            stage.show();
        });

    }

    private void loginUser(String login, String password) {
        DataBaseHandler dataBaseHandler = new DataBaseHandler();
        User user = new User();
        user.setLogin(login);
        user.setPassword(password);
        ResultSet resultSet = dataBaseHandler.getUser(user);
        int count = 0;
        while (true){
            try {
                if (!resultSet.next()) break;
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            count++;
        }
        if(count >= 1){
            System.out.println("Success");
        }
    }
}
```

И его fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>


<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="497.0" prefWidth="699.0" style="-fx-background-color: #2E3349;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/16" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <AnchorPane layoutX="-9.0" layoutY="81.0" prefHeight="419.0" prefWidth="708.0" style="-fx-background-color: #fafafa; -fx-border-radius: 5;">
         <children>
            <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="363.0" prefHeight="45.0" prefWidth="317.0" text="Авторизация">
               <font>
                  <Font name="ft40 Roman" size="44.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <Label layoutX="23.0" layoutY="349.0" opacity="0.13" prefHeight="45.0" prefWidth="317.0" text="Авторизация">
               <font>
                  <Font name="ft40 Roman" size="44.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <Label layoutX="187.0" layoutY="55.0" text="Введите ваш ник:">
               <font>
                  <Font name="ft40 Roman" size="36.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <Label layoutX="154.0" layoutY="171.0" text="Введите ваш пароль:">
               <font>
                  <Font name="ft40 Roman" size="36.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <TextField fx:id="loginField" layoutX="229.0" layoutY="106.0" prefHeight="39.0" prefWidth="251.0" promptText="Fareny">
               <font>
                  <Font name="ft40 Roman" size="22.0" />
               </font>
            </TextField>
            <PasswordField fx:id="passwordField" layoutX="229.0" layoutY="220.0" prefHeight="39.0" prefWidth="251.0" promptText="123456789">
               <font>
                  <Font name="ft40 Roman" size="20.0" />
               </font>
            </PasswordField>
            <Button fx:id="signButton" layoutX="591.0" layoutY="366.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="39.0" prefWidth="103.0" style="-fx-background-color: #2E3349;" text="Войти" textFill="WHITE">
               <font>
                  <Font name="ft40 Roman" size="18.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button fx:id="regButton" layoutX="427.0" layoutY="366.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="39.0" prefWidth="155.0" style="-fx-background-color: #ffcc66;" text="Регистрация">
               <font>
                  <Font name="ft40 Roman" size="18.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
      <Label layoutX="262.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="45.0" prefWidth="176.0" text="MineHelper" textFill="WHITE">
         <font>
            <Font name="ft40 Roman" size="30.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Button fx:id="exitButton" layoutX="557.0" layoutY="18.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="37.0" prefWidth="128.0" style="-fx-background-color: #ffcc66;" text="Exit">
         <font>
            <Font name="ft40 Roman" size="18.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Answer (score 0):

В общем забыл в fxml добавить fx:controller="com.example.myapp.app6Controller" :)